# Count how many times each token appears in each rows of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, text, counting

Say I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['spam_eggs', 'tomato_spam'], columns=['Monty'])
```

I would like to end up with a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   Monty_eggs  Monty_spam  Monty_tomato
0    1.000000    1.000000      0.000000
1    0.000000    1.000000      1.000000
```

That is to say - for each row, count how many times the token appears. The tokens in the original DataFrame are separated by underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), which has a useful `sep` parameter.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['spam_eggs', 'tomato_spam'], columns=['Monty'])

df = df['Monty'].str.get_dummies(sep='_').add_prefix(df.columns[0]+'_')

print(df)

   Monty_eggs  Monty_spam  Monty_tomato
0           1           1             0
1           0           1             1
```